# instance variable in NSManagedObject class acts like a class variable?

Tags: nsmanagedobject, ivar

IOS 5 only, with ARC.  In my Core Data model class:

```
//  Planet.h //

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Planet : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *diameter_km;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *mass_kg;

-(void) setVisited:(BOOL)flag;
-(BOOL) isVisited;

@end

// Planet.m //
 
//#import "Planet.h"

@implementation Planet
 
@dynamic name;
@dynamic diameter_km;
@dynamic mass_kg;
 
BOOL visitedByHumans;       // not a core data entity; just an ivar
 
-(void)setVisited:(BOOL)flag {
    visitedByHumans = flag;
}
-(BOOL)isVisited {
    return visitedByHumans;
}
 
@end
```

I use MagicalRecord to create "Venus" and "Mars".  In my view controller, I use labels and buttons to test the above.  Testing shows that when I "visit" Mars, Venus also becomes visited.  If I switch the ivar visitedByHumans into a non-Core-Data property, it works as expected.  So I'm no longer 'stuck', but I want to understand the ivar thing.

Comment: In other words, the above behaves as if I wrote:
    static BOOL visitedByHumans;

Comment: Yes, in essence. `static` would just confine it's scope, but otherwise you are correct. Either way, it is a global variable.

Comment: Pre-iOS5, non-property instance variables had to be declared in the interface (often declared in a private category).  For iOS5, can't I just make an instance variable as in the above code?  (Terminology clarification: by "instance variable" I simply mean it is not a property and it is not a static or class variable.)

Comment: Yes, but not like you did. Within the source file, before the `@implementation Planet`, declare: `@interface Planet() { BOOL visitedByHumans; } @end`. Just declaring the variable in the source isn't enough, because as we determined earlier, it just becomes globally scoped variable.

Comment: Ok, yes, I confirmed that adding the declaration in the interface produces the behavior I expected.  I thought this was no longer necessary with LLVM and iOS5, but apparently it can't be left out.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vistedByHumans` is not actually an ivar, but a global variable of your subclass `Planet`. So, any and every "planet" instance will appear to be visited regardless of which instance is actually visited. If you want to make it an actual ivar, you need to add a `@property` to your `@interface` much like `name`, `diameter_km`, and `mass_kg` (although, those three of course were generated for your models). e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign,getter=isVisited) BOOL visited;
```

and in your implementation:

```
@synthesize visited=visitedByHumans;
```

or just

```
@synthensize visited;
```

Since you appear to be using those methods (`visited` and `setVisited:`) anyhow, and not really directly accessing `visitedByHumans`.

Also, be sure to remove the line of code

```
BOOL visitedByHumans;
```

and the two method definitions `isVisited` and `setVisited:`. They will be generated for you when you `@synthesize`'d them.

Comment: Making visitedByHumans a property is one way to fix.  The other way is  to declare the variable as discussed in the comments on the original post.  I'll mark this as the answer for the sake of resolving the question.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to be sure based on the information you've presented. Your description doesn't match the code-- despite what you say, `visitedByHumans` is most definitely not an instance variable in that code. This then makes me wonder what the code looked like back before you switched it away from using Core Data for `visitedByHumans`. Basically, you explain that the code wasn't working right when you were using Core Data, but then present entirely different code that doesn't actually use Core Data. I don't know what you were doing when you were trying to use Core Data for this property so I can't tell what you might have been doing wrong. If that declaration of `visitedByHumans` was in the code at that time, it was almost certainly screwing things up for you. Likewise, if you had setters in a managed object subclass that didn't call `super`'s implementation, you'd get bad results. But if you want to know why your Core Data code wasn't working, *paste **that** code*, not some completely different code. Don't make people guess what you're up to when you ask for help.

Comment: That's why I originally pointed you to my github repo, so you'd have all the code.  visitedByHumans was never a Core Data attribute in my code.  It may be bad design to put a variable in my NSManagedObject that isn't tied to a CD attribute, but that was my intent in this particular case.  Bottom line is that I'm trying to understand how to do instance variables that are not properties, and want to make sure the problem isn't because it's a subclass of NSManagedObject (because I know CD does a lot behind the scenes that I don't understand).

Comment: Instance variables are handled the same in NSManagedObject subclasses as in any other class. But this isn't an instance variable, and gschandler does a good job of explaining why and how to fix it.